# Derive a formula for $v_{p}(n !)$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I want to derive a formula for $v_{p}(n !)$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $n$

*Definition.* Let $n$ be an integer. Let $v_p(n)$ denote the largest power $k$ of $p$ such that $p^k|n$. ($p$ is prime)

Examples: $v_2(50)=1$, $v_5(50)=2$, $v_3(50)=0$.

**How can I derive a formula for $v_{p}(n !)$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $n$, can you help, can you add an answer? Thanks...**

Comment: See [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula):  $\nu_p(n!)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\dfrac n{p^i}\right\rfloor,$  where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function.

How many multiples of $p$ are in $n!$?  of $p^2$?  of $p^3$?  etc.